# Is there a generic graphical language to represent chemical reactions?

Tags: software, teaching-lab

I want to show a schematic representation of chemical reactions from start to finish in a way that will include more detailed preparation instructions than a plain chemical formula: volumes, concentrations, waiting time, temperature, etc.

Is there a graphical language for this kind of thing? I'm looking for something more sophisticated than a typical flow chart, and more targeted towards chemical reactions.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a chemistry-UML for diagramming laboratory reactions? If so, I had dug up [this](https://www.edrawsoft.com/laboratory-equipment.php) in response to a query a few months ago.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt yes, kinda. That software is more Visio-like and focuses too much on graphics I don't really need. More UML-like is better.

Comment: I poked around. You might find something of use relating to [process flow diagramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_flow_diagram); or from the [open source diagramming tool Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/), which apparently has support for PFD; or look at [Chemical Markup Language](http://www.xml-cml.org/).